# "for the first time"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "for the first time" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The main goal of this study is to highlight the effect of the blade
>   thickness on the entropy generation analysis of the Wells turbine **for
>   the first time**.

Comment: Grammatically there are no problems. But *conceptually*, I think "highlight" (metaphoric *give prominence to*) doesn't pair well with "for the first time", because when you highlight something, this usually implies it was already known/visible before (you're just *emphasising* it). Since it's a *study*, it would be better to use a more "objective, neutral" term like ***show** the effect...* (or perhaps better, ***investigate***). And for what it's worth, I wouldn't bother with ***for the first time*** - it sounds like you're "bragging" (and can you be *sure* no-one else has ever done this?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is grammatically OK, but if you need to emphasize "for the first time", I would write:

> The main goal of this study is, **for the first time**, to highlight the effect of the blade thickness on the entropy generation analysis of the Wells turbine.

This creates a better flow. [topic][the fact it is the first time][goal]